# Laravel and MongoDB generating "must implement Remindable interface" error

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-4

Im trying to implement this package (https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB) in Laravel. However, i'm having issues when trying to send out password reminders or resets using `Password::remind($credentials);` as it throws the following error from line 216 of `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Reminders/PasswordBroker.php.`

`User must implement Remindable interface.`

The User model starts:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
```

Its using the RemindableInterface so I am not sure why its throwing the error

Answer (score 1):

Check if your User model contains this function:

```
public function getReminderEmail();
```

This is what you need to implement in order to satisfy the RemindableInterface.

Comment: Yes these functions are included

Comment: You most likely have a typo in the function name. PHP Wouldn't complain that the method isn't implemented if it really was. Also, please post the copy&pasted error message, the error message you have above seems written from memory ("User must implement..."), so hidden clues may be in the actual message